# Spark on Yarn IO issues

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When scheduling a spark job on yarn is there a possibility to control home any executors are placed on a physical node?

I currently set the `spark.executor.cores` to 4.

Now when YARN places multiple executors on the same data node it is `4* #numberOfExecutorsOnSameNode`threads trying to read and possibly also swapping as HDFS and the temporary directory of spark reside on the same disks.

So this results in huge issues regarding blocked IO time. Getting SSDs is not an option for now. Are there other things I can try?

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix is to increase `spark.executor.memory` as this might over-allocate memory but prevent too many executors being launched on the same data nodes.